# How to remove the warning message from firebase angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I'm using [@angular/fire emulators](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/emulators/emulators.md) to emulate the authentication process in my firebase angular application. But when I run it, I'm seeing a warning message saying "Running in emulator mode. Do not use with productions credentials":

[image]

I saw in [github issues](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2724) that a feature was implemented in order to hide this message. But I don't find how to do it.

Do you know I to do it?

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but here is my solution as I had to deal with it recently:

1. I inspected the element and found that the warning message has css class **".firebase-emulator-warning"**
2. From there I just defined a style in CSS to hide the warning

   .firebase-emulator-warning {
   display: none;
   }
3. Then I decided it is a good idea to still show it, but make it less intrusive.

For this, I used slightly different styling:

```
/* making firebase emulator warning less intrusive */
.firebase-emulator-warning {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: rgba(245, 66, 66, 0.3) !important;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I really likes this. To extend: I added an :hover line that sets `opacity:0;` to be able to see it fully without the message when hovering.